# Make subfigures as big as possible

Tags: subfloats

I have 6 figures putting them together in two lines (3 subfigure in each line).
There are horizontal white spaces between subfigures (in each line). I am going to use those spaces to make the subfigures as large as possible (while keeping their aspect ration). My code is as follows,

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode, dsfont, color, soul, tikz, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, bbm, bbold, fixmath, mathtools, multirow, boldline, xcolor, colortbl, url, footnote, cite}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio]{x2_RWD.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio]{x4_RWD.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio]{x7_RWD.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio]{x2_NRD.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio]{x4_NRD.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio]{x7_NRD.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please, provide complete but small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. six images (three in line) with heights equal to text height you can't put on one page! welcome to tex.se!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're not exploiting any of the special features of `subfigure` environments -- such as the ability to set captions and to insert labels for cross-referencing purposes, you might as well use plain `minipage` environments.

(In the code below, if you do need to provide `\caption` and `\label` statements, simply change all instances of `\begin{minipage}` and `\end{minipage}` back to `\begin{subfigure}` and `\end{subfigure}`, resp. Of course, be sure to load the `subcaption` package as well.)

To maximize the possible horizontal separation between adjacent graphs, insert `\hfill` (or `\hspace{\fill}`) directives between the `minipage`/`subcaption` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real doc.
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*} 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.325\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{x2_RWD.pdf}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.325\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{x4_RWD.pdf}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.325\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{x7_RWD.pdf}
    \end{minipage}

    %% leaving a blank line is deliberate, to tell TeX that a line break needs to occur
    \medskip
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.325\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{x2_NRD.pdf}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.325\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{x4_NRD.pdf}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.325\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{x7_NRD.pdf}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, posted after the OP provided additional information, in a comment, about the document class and packages he/she employs. About those packages: (a) `fixmath` should only be loaded if Computer Modern fonts are in use -- which is not the case here. (b) `xcolor` and `colortbl` should not be loaded independently. (c) Some packages you load automatically load some other packages; hence, there's no need to load the `color`, `amsmath`, and `amsfonts` packages explicitly. (d) Since all graphs have the same height, the `[t]` position specifiers may be omitted from the `subcaption` setups.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference,demo]{IEEEtran} % omit 'demo' option in real doc. 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % don't load 'colortbl' and 'xcolor' independently from each other
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % no need to load 'url' without 'hyphens' option
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode, soul, 
            tikz, mathtools, amssymb, amsthm,
            multirow, footnote, cite, subcaption, 
            dsfont, bbm, bbold, boldline} 

%% 'fixmath' should only be used if Computer Modern
%% fonts are in use -- which is not the case here

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*} 
    \begin{subfigure}{0.325\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{x2_RWD.pdf}
    \caption{\dots} \label{fig:a} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.325\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{x4_RWD.pdf}
    \caption{\dots} \label{fig:b} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.325\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{x7_RWD.pdf}
    \caption{\dots} \label{fig:c} 
    \end{subfigure}

    %% Leaving a blank line is deliberate, to tell 
    %% LaTeX that a line break needs to occur

    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{0.325\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{x2_NRD.pdf}
    \caption{\dots} \label{fig:d} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.325\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{x4_NRD.pdf}
    \caption{\dots} \label{fig:e} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.325\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{x7_NRD.pdf}
    \caption{\dots} \label{fig:f} 
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Overall figure caption} 
\label{fig:overall}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: but op declare images height equal to text height, what is not possible to fit in one page ... so i wait on his response on my comment :-(

Comment: @Zarko - OP also is setting `keepaspectratio`. Unless the pics are unusually tall (like height >> width), the natural width of the images is going to be the constraining factor for three side-by-side image. Thus, specifying `height=textheight, keepaspectratio` is redundant. Let's see if the OP speaks up and answers your question.

Comment: And what do the minipages do?

Comment: @egreg - The `[t]` position specifiers (carried over from the OP’s own code) will be useful if the graphs don’t all have the same heights. If, however, the three graphs in a given row all have the same heights, the `minipage` “wrappers” could (should!) be removed.

Comment: @Zarko
I tried to put the complete code but it seems the comment becomes too long and I cannot add it. Anyway, at the beginning of the code I have 
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode, dsfont, color, soul, tikz, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, bbm, bbold, fixmath, mathtools, multirow, boldline, xcolor, colortbl, url, footnote, cite}
\begin{document}
.... PREVIOUS CODE ....
\end{document}

Comment: @Mico All of my subfigures are exactly the same size (exactly like those black boxes you drew).

Comment: @Mohammad Please do not add the code as a comment, but as an edit to your question.

Comment: @Mohammad - Please note that I've provided an addendum to incorporate the pieces of information you provided in a number of comments.

Comment: But just to double check, Does `width=\linewidth` keep the aspect ratio? Basically, what is the difference between `\linewidth` and `\textwidth`?

Comment: @Mohammad - In the current context, i.e., a double-wide float, the two macros can be used interchangeably.

Comment: @Mohammad - Unless your graphs are exceedingly tall, the limiting factor is going to be width of the graphs. By all means, go ahead and add the options `height=\textheight` and `keepaspectratio` -- the final result will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need no `subfigure` environment, unless you want subcaptions.

Here the images are horizontally and vertically separated by the same white space, `\lineskip`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo because I don't have your files
\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newlength{\maxfigurewidth}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure*}

\setlength{\maxfigurewidth}{\dimexpr(\textwidth-2\lineskip)/3}

\includegraphics[width=\maxfigurewidth]{x2_RWD.pdf}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=\maxfigurewidth]{x4_RWD.pdf}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=\maxfigurewidth]{x7_RWD.pdf}

\includegraphics[width=\maxfigurewidth]{x2_NRD.pdf}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=\maxfigurewidth]{x4_NRD.pdf}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=\maxfigurewidth]{x7_NRD.pdf}

\caption{Some global caption}\label{whatever}

\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

The `\lineskip` is inserted automatically between the two rows, we insert it manually (with `\hfil`) between the columns.

[image]

If you want no spacing, either between columns or between rows:

```
\begin{figure*}

\setlength{\maxfigurewidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth/3}

\includegraphics[width=\maxfigurewidth]{x2_RWD.pdf}%
\includegraphics[width=\maxfigurewidth]{x4_RWD.pdf}%
\includegraphics[width=\maxfigurewidth]{x7_RWD.pdf}

\nointerlineskip

\includegraphics[width=\maxfigurewidth]{x2_NRD.pdf}%
\includegraphics[width=\maxfigurewidth]{x4_NRD.pdf}%
\includegraphics[width=\maxfigurewidth]{x7_NRD.pdf}

\caption{Some global caption}\label{whatever}

\end{figure*}
```

With subcaptions:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo because I don't have your files
\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newlength{\maxfigurewidth}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure*}

\setlength{\maxfigurewidth}{\dimexpr(\textwidth-2em)/3}

\begin{subfigure}{\maxfigurewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{x2_RWD.pdf}
\caption{one}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{\maxfigurewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{x4_RWD.pdf}%
\caption{two}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{\maxfigurewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{x7_RWD.pdf}
\caption{three}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip

\begin{subfigure}{\maxfigurewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{x2_NRD.pdf}%
\caption{four}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{\maxfigurewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{x4_NRD.pdf}%
\caption{five}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{\maxfigurewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{x7_NRD.pdf}
\caption{six}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Some global caption}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I need subcaptions, however; I haven't included that in my code. sorry!

Comment: Excatly I need something like those blackboxes. But how can I use subfigure?

Comment: @Mohammad I added the solution with subfigure